# How to define generic argument that extends nullable but not nullable itself

Tags: generics, kotlin, nullable

In Kotlin is there a way to define a non-nullable generic argument that is a subtype of nullable type?
I thought that I can do something like

```
class nullableToNonnullable<A: Any?, B> where B: A, B: Any {
    fun toNonNull(a: A): B
}
```

but I'm getting compile time error:

Type parameter cannot have any other bounds if it's bounded by another type parameter

Right now I can only work around it by using a wrapper type, something like `Option`

```
class nullableToNonnullable<A: Any> {
    fun toNonNull(a: Option<A>): A
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly what you are trying to do but

(nullable A) -> (not null A) function

```
class nullableToNonnullable<A: Any> {
    fun toNonNull(a: A?): A
}
```

(nullable A) -> (not null subtype of A) function

```
class nullableToNonnullable<A: Any, B : A> {
    fun toNonNull(a: A?): B
}
```

Here, the type parameter `A` in the class should be given as not null, although the function can input nullable parameters.

I don't think you can restrict one of the class type parameters to be nullable (must not be not null), and one of them to be both a subtype of the former and not null in Kotlin.

And I think you don't need a class in the case in your example.

```
fun <A : Any> toNonNull(a: A?): A
```

and

```
fun <A : Any, B : A> toNonNull(a: A?): B
```

Comment: The solutions with `B` will be using unchecked casts unless they're inline an reified.